# String property bound to binary property

Tags: java, binding, javafx

I wish to set the title of a JavaFX ToggleButton depending of its state:

Imperative Java code:

```
tgBtn.setText( tgBtn.isSelected() ? "Stop" : "Start" );
```

I wish to use JavaFX bindings but I miss a "ternary" operator:

```
tgBtn.textProperty().bind( tgBtn.selectedProperty().asString());
```

With this binding the text of the button becomes:
  [image: When released]   [image: When pressed]

Can you suggest a binding to display "Start" / "Stop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tgBtn.textProperty().bind(
   Bindings.when(tgBtn.selectedProperty())
     .then("Stop")
     .otherwise("Start")
);
```

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I want.